# List the titles of movies that have a higher score than some movie in the database

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm completely stuck on this query. My table is:

```
Movie(MovieID, Title, Year, Score, Votes)
```

How do I list the titles of movies that have a higher score than some movie in the database.

I know this is wrong but something that would accomplish essentially

```
SELECT title FROM movie WHERE score > Alien;
```

Hope I explained myself well enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this

```
Select title from movie where score > (select score from movie where title = 'Alien')
```

Comment: Beat me to it, so instead of posting, upvoting